# How to convert .cpbitmap to readable image (png, jpg, jpeg…)

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, bitmap, jailbreak

I like to convert an .cpbitmap file to an image format that can be displayed in UIImageView. Is there a way to do this in Objective-C? The app will run on jailbroken Devices, so thats not a big deal.

Comment: I doubt you still care considering this was over a year ago, but here's my _working_ code: https://github.com/ZaneH/unsplashwallpaper/blob/master/Listener.xm#L185

Answer (score 3):

Import private `AppSupport.framework` and declare this

```
CFArrayRef CPBitmapCreateImagesFromData(CFDataRef cpbitmap, void*, int, void*);
```

This function will return an array of `CGImageRef` objects. First argument is data from `.cpbitmap` file. Other arguments are unknown to me (one of them is probably `CFAllocatorRef`)  so I checked how iOS calls this function and used the same values. Here is how I did it

```
CPBitmapCreateImagesFromData([NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"LockBackground.cpbitmap"], NULL, 1, NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I have multible questions. Where should I declare "CFArrayRef CPBitmapCreateImagesFromData(CFDataRef cpbitmap, void*, int, void*);", should I declare it in the a header file of AppSupport.framework? And the other question is where did you got the AppSupport.framework, when i import if from here: https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers I get multible errors. Can you please explain it a bit more to me?

Comment: You can declare it anywhere you want in your project. Then you need to import the framework. As it's a private framework you need to find it using the Finder and drag it in your project's `Frameworks` folder. The framework can be found here `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework`

Comment: Hi, that helped me a lot. Sorry for the question, but how do you get the UIImage of it?

Comment: `UIImage` has `imageWithCGImage:` method. If you want to save that image as JPEG or PNG you can use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or  `UIImagePNGRepresentation` respectevly.

Comment: ok, one more question. I import the framework like this, go to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Develope‌​r/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ and drag AppSupport.framework into the framework folder in my xcode project. Then I do #import <AppSupport/> in my ViewControler. But then xcode tells me that the framework isnt there. And shouldnt there be header files in the .framework?

Comment: There is no headers for private frameworks, hence "private". You need to import the framework - this will link it to your app. Now you need to declare the function yourself. Create header file, declare the function and import it in your project just like any other header file. I suggest you read about private APIs, how can you use them in your apps and how this reverse engineering is done. This will answer many of your questions and will give you better understanding of what exactly are we doing here.

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to convert HomeBackground.cpbitmap / LockBackground.cpbitmap from Library/Springboard.

The following worked for me:
@creker: Thank you!

```
CFArrayRef CPBitmapCreateImagesFromData(CFDataRef cpbitmap, void*, int, void*);
CFArrayRef someArrayRef = CPBitmapCreateImagesFromData((__bridge CFDataRef)([NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LockBackground" ofType:@"cpbitmap"]]), NULL, 1, NULL);
NSArray *array = (__bridge NSArray*)someArrayRef;
UIImage *test = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:(__bridge CGImageRef)(array[0])];
```

I added a breakpoint after the last line and extracted the image with XCode -> test -> Preview.